# Driving time around Iceland

Tags: road-trips, iceland

Hi I am going to Iceland the second week of May and was thinking of driving. I would like to have my route down but haven't been able to find anything that gives exact driving directions And duration of time it takes to get to each location. I would like to do the golden circle and the Jokulsarlon glacial lagoon and all the hot spots along the way. Any suggestions. I only have from may 9-12.

Comment: [Related question about camping](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13410/camping-along-ring-road-in-iceland)

Comment: Related questions about [driving](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/driving-in-iceland-a-good-idea) and about the [ring road](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/how-accessible-are-the-dirt-road-parts-of-icelands-ring-road/)

Comment: Driving by car our on bike? Car rentals usually offer at reasonable rates to get a GPS in your car. Even the cheap ones do.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps has:

[image: TSE45493 example]

via Suðurlandsvegur/Þjóðvegur 1 and Route 41 11 h 36 min
958 km 11 h 36 min without traffic

Keflavík International Airport
235, Iceland
Continue to Reykjanesbraut/Route 41
3 min (1.9 km)
Continue on Route 41. Drive from Reykjanesbraut, Vesturlandsvegur and Þingvallavegur to Suðurland
1 h 5 min (87.3 km)
Drive to your destination
3 min (700 m)
1 h 11 min (89.9 km)
Thingvellir
Iceland
Head west
700 m
Turn right toward Þingvallavegur
24 m
Turn right onto Þingvallavegur
15.9 km
Continue straight onto Gjabakkavegur/Gjábakkavegur/Route 365
Continue to follow Route 365
14.3 km
At the roundabout, take the 2nd exit onto Laugarvatnsvegur/Route 37
24.2 km
Continue onto Route 35
5.4 km
Slight left onto Haukadalsvegur
300 m
52 min (60.8 km)
Geysir
Haukadalsvegur, Iceland
Take Biskupstungnabraut and Skeiða- og Hrunamannavegur to Þjóðvegur
43 min (56.1 km)
Follow Þjóðvegur to Austurland
3 h 31 min (306 km)
Turn left
4 h 15 min (362 km)
Jökulsárlón
Head southwest toward Þjóðvegur
290 m
Turn right at the 1st cross street onto Þjóðvegur/Route 1
Continue to follow Route 1
319 km
At the roundabout, take the 1st exit onto Suðurlandsvegur/Route 1
Continue to follow Route 1
1.6 km
At the roundabout, take the 1st exit onto Suðurlandsvegur
Go through 1 roundabout
1.8 km
Turn right onto Biskupstungnabraut
12.8 km
3 h 54 min (336 km)
Kerið
Iceland
Follow Biskupstungnabraut and Suðurlandsvegur to Route 41 in Suðurnes
1 h 19 min (107 km)
Continue on Route 41. Drive to Arrivals
5 min (3.0 km)
1 h 24 min (110 km)
Keflavík International Airport
235, Iceland

Comment: I have done a one day tour (by tour bus) from Reykjavik to Jökulsárlón and back. Started about 7:30 AM to return 11 PM. Most of the time spend driving and with a few shortish stops. If you do drive yourself you would not be able to do it in one day and still see the sights and have your rest.